# Apply Trim(replace...) to all cells on a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a global macro that can format or break the formatting of chr()'s when downloading system reports to excel.  Is there a method that does this faster than what I already have?  I would like for it to avoid looping through each cell as some of these reports can be more than 20 columns and over 25K rows.

```
Sub test123()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange


Dim r As Range

On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In rng1
        r.Value = Trim(Replace(r.Value, Chr(160), Chr(32)))
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim t, cell As Range, rng As Range, arr
Dim nR As Long, nC As Long, r As Long, c As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1").Resize(10000, 20)

    '###### update cell-by-cell ######
    t = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual '<< big speedup here...
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        cell.Value = Replace(Trim(cell.Value), Chr(160), Chr(32))
    Next cell
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic '<<...but don't forget to set back
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print Timer - t  ' about 10sec

    t = Timer

    '###### read to array, update array, write to sheet ######
    arr = rng.Value
    nR = UBound(arr, 1)
    nC = UBound(arr, 2)
    For r = 1 To nR
    For c = 1 To nC
        arr(r, c) = Replace(Trim(arr(r, c)), Chr(160), Chr(32))
    Next c
    Next r
    rng.Value = arr

    Debug.Print Timer - t 'about 0.5 sec

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I apologize for not responding to this right away.  I thought I had accepted the answer.  Great solution on the option at the bottom.  I've never used "UBound" before.  I'm going to read about it to understand the array.